# Screen Capture on Windows 8 view LapTop without PrintScreen key?

Tags: windows-8, screenshot

On Windows 8.x you are allowed to take screen shots on the Windows 8 start screen and apps using the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key. And it works super, with my external keyboard, but not on my built in keyboard.

Problem is I don't have a Print Screen key visible, and the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> doesn't work on the Windows 8 viewport even if selected.

**How do I capture the Windows 8 screen without a Print Screen key?**

[image]

Comment: Does the Fn+F10 work as expected on the Windows *desktop* and in regular desktop-style applications?  Have you tried Shift+Fn+F10 or alike yet?  also, please edit your question to include the exact make and model of your notebook.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It did on half-desktop half-windows8 mode, but not on full screen mode in either desktop nor Windows8 mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Snipping Tool`, which is readily installed in Windows 8. It has 4 options for you choose:

- Free-form snip
- Rectangular snip
- Window snip
- Full-screen snip

Comment: It actually worked! Having half screen in Windows8 and half on desktop it captured all in a full screen snip. Thank you Dai!